# Android App Code Signing without Eclipse on Windows

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed a phonegap app and created an APK but I need to add the signing key.

I've read that it's done with Eclipse but I don't use eclipse to create the apps.

Is there any way to get the signing key without having to use Eclipse?

Note: I'm using windows 7 OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the source code of your project you can build it without Eclipse, signing an unsigned apk can be also achieved using ant

Here is a quick tutorial on how to build signed APK without Eclipse.

Type in to CMD

```
cd your/project/folder/
android update project -p .
```

Add to project.properties the following settings:

```
key.store=path/to/export/key
key.alias=alias_name
key.store.password=store_password
key.alias.password=alias_password
```

Type in to CMD

```
cd your/project/folder/
ant relese
```

**The output APK will be found in the bin folder**

**Note:** that this requires android SDK installed.

if you get the following error:

```
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

You should add your android-sdk/tools and android-sdk/platform-tools to system path, here is a tutorial on how to do it:

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I seem to be doing something wrong here ... I've created a folder and added my .apk file and then typed: android update myproject.apk -p  ... This seems to be wrong ... is it asking for the index.html name there? I'm a bit confused as it's the first time I'm attempting this :)

Comment: As mentioned this method will work on RAW SOURCE CODE ONLY
not a compiled APK. If you want to just sign an unsigned apk, there should be a way to do so via the ANT command, google somthing like "android ant sign apk"

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I feel like the Cordova /PhoneGap getting started docs aren't as clear as they should be on code signing.

Answer (score 2):

You need a signapk.jar that is generated when you build AOSP. And then use the below command
Search for signapk.jar on the internet you will be able to download it.

```
java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 your-app.apk  your-signed-app.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Below Link for Signing to apk file with out eclipse and with eclipse tutorial

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/01/android-signing-apk/