# Phonegap project to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, phonegap-build

I could really use some help here.. I was using Phonegap build to build my (android) app with pretty much some JS, HTML5 and CSS.. I finished the project and was testing it by scanning the QR code and getting it on my android.  Anyways all was fine and I was ready to upload to the android marketplace.  After trying to upload the apk I got an error message saying the app was declared in debug mode (even though i never had debugging enabled in phonegap) after a little more research I then found out that I need to be running this in Eclipse and it needs to be signed.  So I read the android documentation on signing and what not but I have no idea how to get over this hump.

I am like a lost puppy because I dont know eclipse and the app is finished.  So I try to import my already done files into eclipse how I think I should be importing it and I get the error message that AndroidManifest.xml cant be found..  I have no idea the steps I need to take next, I am guessing I just need to import this puppy into eclipse so I can sign it and then I am assuming I will be able to upload to the marketplace?

Any advice for me knowing where I am in my project and what I need to do to get this off the ground?  I am a complete noob and feel so lost.

**[edit]** it may be worth noting that I built this with Phonegap build and altough I do not have AndroidManifest.xml, I do have config.xml and all I really need to know is how to apply my signing key and I guess keep google marketplace from seeing it as being in "debug" mode.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can do it without eclipse. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12017808/121668). Search better [like this](http://bit.ly/Ww5BvW). Fourth answer down is SO link.

Comment: I appreciate the links but I am still so lost on how to do this without eclipse, and I followed the tutorials you sent but still cant get it.. possible my paths or off or what?

Comment: Yes you are hosed if you don't have your path variables set. Elaborate on "can't get it". What issues are you having?

Comment: I ended up just using the eclipse side of things and so far so  good, link is http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Hope this helps someone else, thanks for the help guys..